# How can i get rid of the open space between the topside of my website and my navigation bar (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When i tried to make my navbar static I came across something weird. I am having a space between the navbar and the topside of my website.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this so that my navbar will be in the place of the open space? (I am bad at explaining things i know....)

```
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">BlahBlahism</a>

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target= ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>   
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

There is no CSS involved

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS for navbar ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine when i tried running.
but still you should try using this.
some versions of internet explorer do not support class nav or nav-bar please check

hope this would help

```
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your code says, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the default behaviour of the elements in question.

Possible solution:
Make a little CSS and remove padding and/or margin.

```
<style>
#theNavbarID{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Post some code and I'll expand upon it if need be.

EDIT:
Code works just fine, you can try it here:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fvpjudo/)

Comment: I tried to remove the paddings and margins. This results in the removal of the padding/margin on the links in the navbar

Comment: The code you provided works fine for me, it's probably in another part of the code. Copy the code over into a new html file, then disect it piece by piece until you're left with only the erring part, it'll be easier to find the problem then. One other thing it could be is if you included any stylesheets, they may be affecting it.

Comment: could you put in the CSS you added?

Comment: Well I don't think you'll need it, you can see for yourself what I and Mayur saw: https://jsfiddle.net/9fvpjudo/